# How do I call a specific field in a model into another model?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I am new to django. I wanted to know if it was possible to call a specific field in a model into another model.

The goal is to update a the quantity of a specific product in the database and generate a receipt for it.

Here's the example:

models.py:

```
class Product(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True)
   price = models.FloatField(null=True)
   quantity = models.IntegerField(default='0', blank=True, null=True)

class UpdateStock(models.Model):
  date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
  wayBill_Number = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True)
  product_Name = models.ForeignKey(Product.name, null=True, on_delete= models.SET_NULL)
  quantity = models.ForeignKey(Product.quantity, null=True, on_delete= models.SET_NULL)
```

I just want to select the product and the quantity to update in the database but I am unable to do so.

Answer (score 0):

A `ForeignKey` is supposed to refer to another model, not to one of its fields.

So the first thing you have to do it to edit your `UpdateStock` model this way :

```
 class UpdateStock(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    wayBill_Number = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True)
    product = models.ForeignKey('Product', null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL) # Here
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default='0', blank=True, null=True) # Here
```

So you can bound your product to your stock_update when you create it:

```
stock_update = UpdateStock.objects.create(..., product=your_product_obj, ...)
```

And you will then be able to access any product's field from this stock_update:

```
product = stock_update.product
print(product.quantity)
product.quantity = product.quantity + stock_update.quantity
print(product.quantity)
product.save()
```

But I **strongly** advise you to read more about many-to-one relationships [in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/).